# How to check time overlap in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, time, datepicker

I have 4 startTime datePicker and 4 endTime datePicker in my View.
I want to check time is overlap or not.

```
Ex. slot 1 = 09:00 - 12:00
slot 2 = 08:00 - 11:00
slot 3 = 05:00 - 10:30
slot 4 = 11:00 - 16:00
```

I convert this time to decimal with using this formula:

**(Minutes + (Hours*6))/10**

Now I have decimal time, So I tried below code:

```
for item in validationArray! {
            let startIndexvalue:Int = item["startTime"]!
            let stopIndexvalue:Int = item["stopTime"]!

            print(startIndexvalue)
            print(stopIndexvalue)
            print(fastLinkStartTime)

            if stopIndexvalue > startIndexvalue {
                if startIndexvalue ... stopIndexvalue ~= fastLinkStartTime {

                    if startIndexvalue == 0 {
                        validationTimeDic["startTime"] = fastLinkStartTime
                        timeDic["startTime"] = hours + "0"
                    }

                    else {
                        showValidationAlert(title: NSLocalizedString("You can not select time in between existing time slot.", comment: ""), message: "")
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.StartTime.text = "--:--"
                        }

                        validationTimeDic["startTime"] = 0
                        timeDic["startTime"] = "--:--"
                    }

                    validationArray?[currentRow] = validationTimeDic
                    self.currentObject!.validationData[currentSection.description] = validationArray

                    array?[currentRow] = timeDic
                    self.currentObject!.mondayToSundayData[currentSection.description] = array

                    print(self.currentObject!.validationData)

                }
            }
```

Please give me any idea to do this?

Comment: @SPatel actually SO is a solution provider. I think what you meant is "you won't get help if you did not put any effort into solving it yourself".

Comment: @SPatel which is exactly my point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  for i in 0..<validationArray!.count {
                var currentItem = validationArray![i]
                let currentStart:Int = currentItem["startTime"]!
                let currentEnd:Int = currentItem["stopTime"]!
                if currentStart != 0 && currentEnd != 0 {
                    if i < (validationArray?.count)! - 1  {
                        let nextItem = validationArray![i+1]
                        let nextStart:Int = nextItem["startTime"]!
                        let nextEnd:Int = nextItem["stopTime"]!
                        if currentEnd > currentStart {
                            if nextEnd  <  currentStart {
                                currentItem["stopTime"] = fastLinkStopTime
                                timeDic["stopTime"] = hours + "0"
                            }
                            else if nextStart >  currentEnd {
                                currentItem["stopTime"] = fastLinkStopTime
                                timeDic["stopTime"] = hours + "0"
                            }
                            else {
                                showValidationAlert(title: NSLocalizedString("Your heating time is in an already set heating interval.", comment: ""), message: "")
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    self.StopTime.text = "--:--"
                                }
                                fastLinkStopTime = 255
                                timeDic["stopTime"] = "--:--"
                                dataArray?[currentRow] = timeDic
                                self.currentObject!.mondayToSundayData[currentSection.description] = dataArray
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            showValidationAlert(title: NSLocalizedString("Please check your entry. The start time must not be before the end time.", comment: ""), message: "")
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.StopTime.text = "--:--"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to check if two `Date` ranges overflaps. This you can do by checking if one `ClosedRange<Date>` overlaps the other

```
let isOverlapping = (startDate1...endDate1).overlaps(startDate2...endDate2)
```

---

But for your case, you don’t want to append this time (in your case `Int` index) to array if it overlaps with any other time in array, so before you append this new time check if overlaps with some other time. If doesn’t append it, if does, do whatever you want to.

```
let array: [[String: Int]] = ...
let newStartIndex: Int = ...
let newEndIndex: Int = ...
let isOverlapping = array.allSatisfy { $0["startTime"] <= newEndIndex && newStartIndex <= $0["stopTime"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend Range class for this use or you can use intersection on CGRect class.

// CGRect usage

```
var r1 = CGRect(x: 4.8, y: 0, width: 1.8, height: 1)
var r2 = CGRect(x: 5.8, y: 0, width: 2, height: 1)
var r3 = CGRect(x: 6, y: 0, width: 0.8, height: 1)

r1.intersection(r2).intersection(r3)
```

// ClosedRange usage

```
extension CountableClosedRange where Bound == Int {
        func intersection(_ range: CountableClosedRange<Int>) -> CountableClosedRange<Int>? {
            if(self.lowerBound >= range.upperBound) {
                return nil;
            }
            if(self.upperBound <= range.lowerBound) {
                return nil;
            }
            return CountableClosedRange(uncheckedBounds:
                (lower: self.lowerBound > range.lowerBound ?
                    self.lowerBound
                    :range.lowerBound,
                 upper: self.upperBound < range.upperBound ?
                    self.upperBound
                    :range.upperBound))
        }
    }

    func convertTime(h:Int, m: Int = 0) -> Int {
        return m+h*60;
    }
    var range1 = CountableClosedRange(uncheckedBounds: (lower: 48 , upper: 56))
    var range2 = CountableClosedRange(uncheckedBounds: (lower: 53 , upper: 55))
    var range3 = CountableClosedRange(uncheckedBounds: (lower: 45 , upper: 54))
    var range4 = CountableClosedRange(uncheckedBounds: (lower: 47 , upper: 64))
    let arr = [range2,range3,range4]
    var resultRange:CountableClosedRange<Int>? = range1
    for item in arr {
        resultRange = resultRange?.intersection(item)
    }
```